# Insert space after bullet in <ul> <li>

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to put some padding after the bullet in `<ul>` `<li>` but then the circles doesn't look good.

Html code is:

```
<div class="footer_ticker">
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">See the latest from our COMMENTARY page....</a></li>
      <li><a href="">USDTRY - Tracking Channel Higher</a></li>
      <li><a href="">USDMXN - Demand accelerates after setback </a></li>
    </ul>
  </marquee>
</div>
```

Demo: -- https://jsfiddle.net/wd84undd/

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding  `margin-right:3px;`
to footer_ticker ul li::before {

Comment: Worked :).. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to add space between the bullet and the text?

Add margin (or padding if you wish) to the left of your `a` tag.

```css
.footer_ticker ul li::before {
  background-color: #60d9eb;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 5px;
}
.footer_ticker ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 17px;
  list-style: outside none disc;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.footer_ticker ul li a {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer_ticker">
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">See the latest from our COMMENTARY page....</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">USDTRY - Tracking Channel Higher</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">USDMXN - Demand accelerates after setback </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.